# PHP array map to anther array

Tags: php, arrays, dictionary, array-map

I need to map

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
                [cid] => 1
                [value] => red
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
                [cid] => 2
                [value] => green
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
                [cid] => 3
                [value] => pink
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
                [cid] => 4
                [value] => yellow
        )
)
```

To:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 1
)
```

I need to map the `second` arrays value [0] => 2 to the cid in the `first` array. In other words I need 2 to map to value green.

Any help? THANK YOU.

Comment: What is the logic here? Where does the order in the new array come from, and why isn't `4` in the result?

Comment: Is `2, 3, 1` the result or a second input array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would first change the first array to something that is easier to check.

```
<?php
$temp = array();
foreach ($array1 as $val) {
  $temp[$val['cid']] = $val['value'];
}
?>
```

Now you have an array:

```
$temp[1] = "red";
$temp[2] = "green";
$temp[3] = "pink";
$temp[4] = "yellow";
```

Then you can easily use that in the second array

```
<?php
$new= array();
foreach ($array2 as $key=>$val) {
  $new[$key] = $temp[$val];
}
?>
```

[Codepad example](http://codepad.org/pGKe8Fl8)

Comment: Took me a few minutes to realize what he wanted, you beat me to writing it.

Answer (score 2):

**PHP >= 5.5.0**

```
$colors = array_column($first, 'value', 'cid');

foreach($second as $value) {
    if(isset($colors[$value])) {
        echo $colors[$value];
    }
}
```

Where `$first` is your first array and `$second` obviously the second.